# Can't figure out why OpenGL frame buffer object status = 0

Tags: c++, opengl

The following code prints that the FBO's status is 0. That means an error occured, but I don't understand where.

```
    unsigned int SHADOW_WIDTH = 1024;
    unsigned int SHADOW_HEIGHT = 1024;

    unsigned int depthMapFBO;
    unsigned int depthMap;

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthMapFBO);

    glGenTextures(1, &depthMap);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

    auto fboStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(depthMapFBO);
    if (fboStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "Framebuffer not complete: " << fboStatus << std::endl;
```

Comment: glCheckFramebufferStatus: `Additionally, if an error occurs, zero is returned.` Have you tried calling glGetError to see if you get more information?

Comment: @Borgleader yes I tried glGetError and it indicated no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GLenum glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLenum target);
```

The parameter has to be a target, not the name of the framebuffer object.

[glCheckFramebufferStatus](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xhtml)

> *target*
>
> Specify the target to which the framebuffer is bound for glCheckFramebufferStatus

In your case, that would be `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`.

Since `glCheckFramebufferStatus` returns zero and not one of the defined values:

> Additionally, if an error occurs, zero is returned